# Method overloading with the same signature in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, overloading

```
class testClass(object):
    def test1(self):
        print "1"
    def test1(self):
        print "2"
    def test1(self):
        print "3"
```

This is a Class containing three methods which all have the same name (and even same signature)

When I call this:

```
tc = testClass()
tc.test1()
```

it's not throwing any error, but simplt printing `3`.

One more example:

```
class testClass(object):
    def test1(self, a, b):
        print "1"
    def test1(self, a):
        print "2"
    def test1(self, a, b, c):
        print "3"
```

Again if I call `tc.test1()`, it raises an exception:

```
TypeError: test1() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

So can I assume that in these situations it will always execute the last method defined in the class?

PS: I tried the same with individual functions in a file and got the same result, it executed the last function.

Comment: Python is not Java. [Five-minute Multimethods in Python](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605).

Comment: A recording you replace the function, and therefore executed last. For an unspecified number of parameters, read about *args and **kwargs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, when Python encounters a class statement, it executes the `def` statements in order to create the correct name bindings for the ensuing class namespace (`__dict__`).

As with running the interpeter, names that get re-defined lose their old value; it gets replaced with *the most recent assignment to that specific name.*

There's no method overloading in python, because we have those nice keyword arguments that allow us make 'overloaded' calls however we need them:

```
class A:
    def f(self, a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
        print(a, b, c, d, sep=" | ")


a = A()

a.f(1)
# out : 1 | None | None | None

a.f(1, 2)
# out : 1 | 2 | None | None

a.f(1, 2, 3)
# out : 1 | 2 | 3 | None

a.f(1, 2, 3, 4)
# out : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

---

As a final note, just because Python doesn't offer you inherent overloading it doesn't mean that you can't implement the functionality yourself.

After a bit of searching I found a nice example of this in *[this repo](https://github.com/bintoro/overloading.py)* that exposes an `@overloaded` and `@overloads(func)` decorator for overloading functions:

```
from overloading import *

@overloaded
def f():
    return 'no args'

@overloads(f)
def f(foo):
    return 'one arg of any type'

@overloads(f)
def f(foo:int, bar:int):
    return 'two ints'

>>> f()
'no args'
>>> f('hello')
'one arg of any type'
>>> f('hello', 42)
TypeError: Invalid type or number of arguments when calling 'f'.
```

Got to love the Python Community.

Answer (score 3):

> So can I assume that in these situation it will always execute last method in the class?

You got that right. Your first example is equivalent to:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
print x
>> 3
```